# How to unit test express middleware function that calls res.cookie

Tags: unit-testing, express, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I am trying to unit test my own express middleware function, using mocha, chai and sinon.

Basically this function checks for a `token` paramter on `req.query`, and if it exists, adds a cookie with the value of `token`.

```
function tokenRedirect(req, res, next) {
    const qs = require('querystring');

    if (req.query && req.query.token) {
        res.cookie('token', req.query.token);
    } else {
        next();
        return;
    }

    res.redirect('/');
}
```

I know I could do something like:

```
res = { cookie: sinon.spy() };
```

and then

```
assert(res.cookie.calledWith('token', expectedToken));
```

But what I want to do is check that `req.cookies` actually has the cookie im expecting it to have, like so:

```
assert.equal(req.cookies.token, expectedToken);
```

The problem is that `res`, `req`, and all their properties are just mocks I create for the test, so the `res.cookie` is not the actual express function that really adds cookies to the `req` object.

How can I pass a real express `res` object to my function? Is it even possible?

I hope I was clear enough, unit testing is a new concept for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the actual `req` and `res` objects that come from Express would fall more under integration tests (correct me if I'm wrong). Unit test focus solely on your code and all other external dependencies should be mocked, again correct me if I'm wrong here in comments.

Instead of mocking the `res` with `sion`, you would need to partially mock/implement that logic that Express uses [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L827). So something like (using Jest):

```
const tokenRedirect = require('../location/to/middleware/tokenRedirect')

describe('tokenRedirect', () => {
  /**
   * Mocked Express Request object.
   */
  let req

  /**
   * Mocked Express Response object.
   */
  let res

  /**
   * Mocked Express Next function.
   */
  let next = jest.fn()

  beforeEach(() => {
    req = {
      body: {}
    }

    res = {
      query: {},
      headers: {},
      data: null,
      json(payload) {
        this.data = JSON.stringify(payload)
      },
      cookie(name, value, options) {
          this.headers[name] = value
      }
    }

    next.mockReset()
  })

  test('should correctly set cookie', async () => {
    const expectedToken = 'expected'
    res.query.token = ''

    tokenRedirect(req, res, next)

    expect(res.headers.token).toBeDefined()
    expect(res.headers.token).toEqual(expectedToken)
  })
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
What would be the 'correct' way of testing:
1. Test that the output of the function is what I expect
Or
2. Test every step of my function, as in checking that inner functions were called with the right arguments.

Comment: "Correct" is entirely opinion based. Testing is a complex topic on its own with widely varying answers. I've updated the sample above with a small example.